# How far will the Eagle Eye spell let me see on the open ocean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, vision-and-light

How far will the [Eagle Eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/eagle-eye) spell let me see on the open ocean?

> Eagle eye creates a magical sensor directly above you. The sensor can appear anywhere above you, to a maximum height equal to the spell's range.

It is a long-range spell.  Obviously this is a long long way, but the spell doesn't specify how far away I can see.  Obviously in many situations it'd limited by obstructions, but this spell should really shine on the open sea.  How far can I see with Eagle Eye at its maximum height on the open ocean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The maximum height would be 1200 feet (400 + 800 for level).

I assume you could see out to the horizon on the open sea.

For an earth-like world, [distance to the horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Distance_to_the_horizon) is approximately 46.26 miles at that height.

Expanded details:

If this were a druid caster:

- At level 3, the height would be 520 for a distance of 27.82 miles.  (Minimum caster level)
- At level 5, the height would be 600 for a distance of 29.88 miles.
- At level 10, the height would be 800 for a distance of 34.51 miles.
- At level 15, the height would be 1000 for a distance of 38.58 miles.
- **At level 20, the height would be 1200 for a distance of 42.26 miles.**

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on [Maximillian's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16856/how-far-will-the-eagle-eye-spell-let-me-see-on-the-open-ocean/16857#16857):

> At level 20, the height would be 1200 for a distance of 46.26 miles.

At that kind of a distance, the smallest object or detail a healthy human eye can detect under good light and atmospheric conditions must be approximately 40 feet (~12m) on its smallest dimension facing the viewer.

Under ideal conditions (clear skies, bright sun, no atmospheric haze or fog), smaller sailboats would only be visible as a single dot in the horizon, it would be impossible to identify them. It may be possible to see individual sails on a large ship and get an idea about its rigging, but it would be impossible to identify any markings. At such a distance, forget about seeing a single human being. A human would barely be detectable at around 6 miles, assuming he's dressed in blacks and walking on white salt flats under a scorching sun.

Comment: Orange or red probably provides a better contrast against white (there's usually little dark spots wandering about, due to eyes moving and somewhat uneven light from the white background). But, yeah.

Comment: The amount of useful detail you could see at that distance (gender, activity, weapons, etc.) would come down to a perception check with DC modifiers for distance and other conditions, certainly color of the clothing could factor in. :)

Comment: At 6 miles, a human being would practically be a small ant (red or black). Any bits of useful information would hardly be visible even at around half a mile.

Comment: Would the increasing height of Eagle Vision actually make it harder to discern details as you go up in level?

Comment: Yes, more the distance to the target, harder it is to discern details.

Comment: Functionally, in game, you'd use the hypotenuse of the triangle to calculate the DC for the perception check.  At DC + 1/10ft, that adds up fast.  Even taking 20 on the check, it gets harder as that distance increases.

Answer (score 1):

Horizon on Earth distance is:

d=1.22√(h)
d = distance in miles
h = height in feet.

More than you care to know about the issue is on Wikipedia's [Horizon entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon)

Answer (score 0):

[Maximillian's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16856/how-far-will-the-eagle-eye-spell-let-me-see-on-the-open-ocean/16857#16857) is a really good description of how the size of the field of vision increases in an area with no obstructions (i.e. on the open ocean).

I think the other part of the OP's question is, given a perfectly clear field, how far can you actually see in detail.

This would be a matter of [perception](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/perception.html), since in the description of the [*eagle eye*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/eagleEye.html#eagle-eye-) spell, it specifically states:

> You can see from this vantage as if you were actually there, rotating your viewpoint 360 degrees. You perceive with your **normal visual senses**.

So, depending on ambient light and atmospheric conditions (humidity, etc), there will be positive or negative DC modifiers... Including a +1/10ft DC modifier for distance.  How far you can see is limited only by your perception.

Comment: So, while I'll freely admit that I think DC +1/10ft is crude and unweildy, it's what is in the book. This translates to a DC +528 at one mile (5280 feet). Of course other modifiers come in to play, like size, color (camouflage -vs- contrast), movement, atmospheric conditions (clear -vs- haze) etc. So you'd see land (very low DC) LONG before a creature on the shore. The final DC is in the GM's hands. The character's perception bonus, even with a Take 20 -vs- the DC still doesn't allow you to SEE to the limits of the spell field of vision.